# How to get identity of sender in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Since swift 3 some AnyObject type has been set to Any.
However I can't seem to access the sender tag.

I first had

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (saveButton === sender) {
        let name = nameField.text ?? ""
        program = Program(id: -1, name: name, type: capsulesTypes![typeSelected], planning: planningString, date: timePicker.date.timeIntervalSince1970, intensity: Int(intensitySlider.value), enabled: false)
        sendProgramToAPI(program!)
    }
```

It worked well in Swift 2 when sender was an AnyObject. However now the condition is always wrong. So I tried using tag.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if (saveButton.tag == sender.tag) {
    let name = nameField.text ?? ""
    program = Program(id: -1, name: name, type: capsulesTypes![typeSelected], planning: planningString, date: timePicker.date.timeIntervalSince1970, intensity: Int(intensitySlider.value), enabled: false)
    sendProgramToAPI(program!)
}
```

But I have an error saying Any? has no member tag. The tag is basically lost in space and time forevermore.

Any idea to identify the sender somehow ?

Comment: __1.__ typecast, __2.__ access to the instance's properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast the sender's type. If you are sure that the sender is always a `UIButton`, you can do the following:

```
if saveButton.tag == (sender as! UIButton).tag {
```

Or, if you'd rather not use the `tag` property, this should work too:

```
if saveButton == (sender as! UIButton) {
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: God.. I was so confused by that `Any`thing that I simply forgot I was first dealing with a simple Button. Thank you mate!

Comment: You don't need all those brackets. Also, I'd recommend a safer approach which doesn't involve force casts: `guard let button = sender as? UIButton, button === saveButton else { return }`

Answer (score 0):

Your first way was excellent. To use it, just cast back to AnyObject:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (saveButton === sender as AnyObject) {
```